# unattended-upgrades do not work properly

Tags: upgrade, unattended-upgrades

I have

```
Welcome to Ubuntu 16.04.5 LTS (GNU/Linux 4.15.0-24-generic x86_64)

15 packages can be updated.
7 updates are security updates.
```

I watched this several weeks and tried so many things to fix it, but I cant get it run. Unattended-upgrades do not upgrade my server.

I installed

```
# apt-get install unattended-upgrades
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
unattended-upgrades is already the newest version (0.90ubuntu0.9).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 9 not upgraded.

# apt-get install apt-listchanges
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
apt-listchanges is already the newest version (2.85.14ubuntu1).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 9 not upgraded.
```

This is my /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/10periodic

```
APT::Periodic::Update-Package-Lists "1";
APT::Periodic::Download-Upgradeable-Packages "1";
APT::Periodic::AutocleanInterval "7";
APT::Periodic::Unattended-Upgrade "1";
```

This is my /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/50unattended-upgrades

```
Unattended-Upgrade::Allowed-Origins {
        "${distro_id}:${distro_codename}";
        "${distro_id}:${distro_codename}-security";
        "${distro_id}ESM:${distro_codename}";
        "${distro_id}:${distro_codename}-updates";
};

Unattended-Upgrade::Package-Blacklist {
        "open-vm-tools";
};

Unattended-Upgrade::AutoFixInterruptedDpkg "true";
Unattended-Upgrade::MinimalSteps "true";
Unattended-Upgrade::InstallOnShutdown "true";
Unattended-Upgrade::Mail "root";
Unattended-Upgrade::MailOnlyOnError "true";
Unattended-Upgrade::Remove-Unused-Dependencies "true";
Unattended-Upgrade::Automatic-Reboot "true";
Unattended-Upgrade::Automatic-Reboot-Time "07:00";
Acquire::http::Dl-Limit "0";
```

This is what I have in log-file /var/log/unattended-upgrades/unattended-upgrades.log

```
INFO Initial blacklisted packages: open-vm-tools
INFO Initial whitelisted packages:
INFO Starting unattended upgrades script
INFO Allowed origins are: ['o=Ubuntu,a=xenial', 'o=Ubuntu,a=xenial-security', 'o=UbuntuESM,a=xenial', 'o=Ubuntu,a=xenial-updates']
INFO Initial blacklisted packages: open-vm-tools
INFO Initial whitelisted packages:
INFO Starting unattended upgrades script
INFO Allowed origins are: ['o=Ubuntu,a=xenial', 'o=Ubuntu,a=xenial-security', 'o=UbuntuESM,a=xenial', 'o=Ubuntu,a=xenial-updates']
```

Does anyone have a clue what is wrong?

Answer (score 9):

Contrary to the [answer above](https://askubuntu.com/a/1064717/959040) my: "`/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/50unattended-upgrades`" *did* have:

> ```
> Unattended-Upgrade::InstallOnShutdown "false";
> ```

Yet I *still* was seeing:

> ```
> Welcome to Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS (GNU/Linux [...] x86_64)
> [...]
> 29 packages can be updated.
> 0 updates are security updates.
> ```

So why were these 29 packages not updated?

As it turns out, "`/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/50unattended-upgrades`" also contained *this* declaration:

> ```
> Unattended-Upgrade::Allowed-Origins {
>         "${distro_id}:${distro_codename}";
>         "${distro_id}:${distro_codename}-security";
>         // Extended Security Maintenance; doesn't necessarily exist for
>         // every release and this system may not have it installed, but if
>         // available, the policy for updates is such that unattended-upgrades
>         // should also install from here by default.
>         "${distro_id}ESM:${distro_codename}";
> //      "${distro_id}:${distro_codename}-updates";
> //      "${distro_id}:${distro_codename}-proposed";
> //      "${distro_id}:${distro_codename}-backports";
> };
> ```

The key to a fix for me was simply to uncomment this line:

> ```
> //      "${distro_id}:${distro_codename}-updates";
> ```

Comment: From my understanding, by default, only the security updates are installed automatically. This can prevent unwanted surprises sometimes.

Answer (score 5):

If it's still not working after following [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1173642/1196028) by @cuedee, you can try doing a dry run and see if you get some sort of error message or warning.

```
sudo unattended-upgrades -v -d
```

In my case the output explained that my connection was metered (hotspot from mobile phone), and unattended-upgrades by default doesn't allow updates over metered connections. I changed it with the following line in `/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/50unattended-upgrades`:

```
Unattended-Upgrade::Skip-Updates-On-Metered-Connections "false";
```

Comment: For me, running `sudo unattended-upgrades -v -d` works fine and all security updates get installed. Yet, when I leave the service to auto-update my machine, it does nothing! I can see that the `unattended-upgrades.service` service status is `active (running)`. Only a warning is appearing: `Warning: some journal files were not opened due to insufficient permissions.`. So, go figure... I will try to check `cat /var/log/unattended-upgrades/unattended-upgrades.log` next time.

Answer (score 4):

I found the reason:

```
Unattended-Upgrade::InstallOnShutdown "true";
```

This means that updates are only installed before a shutdown. Since  this machine is a 24/7 server updates never happened.

Answer (score 0):

Another *great* reason that is hard to track down is if your `/tmp` or `/var/` directory is mounted `noexec` as per any common CC guide.
It'll cause post-inst scripts to fail and as such block the updates eternally. I don't know a safe solution for this, but suspect there's a way to tell apt to change the mount flags prior/after installing.